# How is leprosy like snow?

Tags: hebrew, word-study, law, leviticus

צָרַעַת, traditionally translated as leprosy, (perhaps skin disease is more accurate) is compared to snow in three locations:

> Exodus 4:6 (ESV) 6 Again, the Lord said to him, "Put your hand inside
> your cloak." And he put his hand inside his cloak, and when he took it
> out, behold, his hand was leprous like snow.
>
> Numbers 12:10 (ESV) 10 When the cloud removed from over the tent,
> behold, Miriam was leprous, like snow. And Aaron turned toward Miriam,
> and behold, she was leprous.
>
> 2 Kings 5:27 (ESV) 27 Therefore the leprosy of Naaman shall cling to
> you and to your descendants forever." So he went out from his presence
> a leper, like snow.

Some versions, such as the NIV, translate “white as snow” although the Hebrew lacks the word “white”.

Regarding this comparison, the *IVP Bible Background Commentary Old Testament* on **2 Kings 5:27** states:

> Comparison to "snow" most likely concerns the flakiness rather than
> the color.

How is leprosy like snow? Its color, its flakiness, or both? And what is the evidence for making such a claim that it only refers to its flakiness?

Comment: Link for Wikipedia on leprosy for full details :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leprosy

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason to conclude that the comparison between leprosy and snow refers to the flakiness of the latter. Instead, we find in two other Bible passages a clue that makes tip the balance in favour of the colour hypothesis.

In fact, speaking about the immediate starting of leprosy on the forehead of Uzziah, 2Chr 26:19 says (bold is mine): "*Then Uzziah was wroth; and he had a censer in his hand to burn incense; and while he was wroth with the priests, **the leprosy broke forth** in his forehead before the priests in the house of the LORD, beside the altar of incense*." (JPS)

The verbal form here translated 'broke forth' in Hebrew is זרחה, and derived from the MT root זרח, 'to be radiant, to rise' ("*as the sun, light, glory, leprosy* [...]", Benjamin Davidson's *Analytical Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon*). See, for yourself the usage of this verb in Job 9:7, relating it to the sunlight.

In conclusion, in all probability, **the matching between 'leprosy' and 'snow' is related to the sparkling whiteness of both, not to a factor due to a presumed flakiness**.